# Conditionally set session data in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, session

i want to set my session data in my view but Conditionally, so in javascript portion of my view i have

```
$('#demo').click(function(){
$this->session->set_userdata('sample',10);
});
```

However , whenever i refresh my page , without clicking the button , the session data , "sample" is set, is there a way i can get this session data set ONLY after i click the button ?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're mixing Javascript and PHP (client-side and server-side). You can do it by using Ajax like this:

```
$('#demo').click(function(){
  $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "mycontroller/sessions"
   }).done(function( msg ) {
     alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
   });
});
```

And in your `Mycontroller.php` file, you should create a function called "sessions":

```
function sessions(){
   $this->session->set_userdata('sample',10);
}
```

If you need to pass information from Javascript to PHP:

```
var dummy = 10;
$('#demo').click(function(){
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "mycontroller/sessions",
      data: { value: dummy }
   }).done(function( msg ) {
      alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
   });
});


function sessions($value){
   $this->session->set_userdata('sample',$value);
}
```

More information about Ajax in JQuery http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

EDIT:

To check if a session variable exists in CodeIgniter:

```
function sessions(){
   $sId = $this->session->userdata('session_id');
   if(isset($sId)){
      // session_id exist
   }
}
```

Section "Retrieving Session Data" http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: that helps , but do we have a technique in codeigniter to check whether a session variable has been set before or not ?

Comment: hmm say anywhere in my code i have not set "session_id" at all , will codeigniter throw me an erro when i do 

    $sId = $this->session->userdata('session_id');

thanks , really appreaciated :D

Comment: @user1537158 `session_id` is just an example. You should specificate your own session var (in the code that you post, your session var is 'sample').

Comment: yes that i understood , but if i have scenario wherein , i have not set the session id yet and somewhere in my code i check 

     if($this->session->userdata('something_not_yet_set'));

will codeigniter give me an error or return false ?

Answer (score 2):

The following method returns FALSE if variable in session is not set

```
$this->session->userdata('sample')
```

Otherwise it returns the appropriate value.